# Keeping values in an array after loop so the values can be used again

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an array which values are calculated in a loop as shown:

```
Sub btnEnter_click()
Dim partno As String
Dim batch1 As String
Dim start1 As Integer
Dim left1(5 To 248) As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim taken(5 To 248) As Integer
Dim vlookres As String

On Error Resume Next
For m = 5 To 248
    partno = Sheet5.Range("A" & m)
    batch1 = Sheet5.Range("B" & m)
    start1 = Sheet5.Range("D" & m)
    vlookres = Application.VLookup(partno, Sheet3.Range("A5:C46"), 3, False)
    If vlookres = "" Then
        vlookres = 0
    End If

    taken(m) = taken(m) + vlookres
    vlookres = 0
    If taken(m) >= batch1 Then
        taken(m) = 0
    End If
    If left1(m) = 0 Then
        left1(m) = start1 - taken(m)
    Else
        left1(m) = left1(m) - taken(m)
    End If
    Sheet5.Range("E" & m) = left1(m)
 Next m

Sheet3.Cells.Range("C5:C46").ClearContents
```

End Sub

The array **left1** is the amount left in a batch and its purpose is to display how much is left in a batch to the user. I am using this if statement to calculate what should be displayed.

```
If left1(m) = 0 Then
        left1(m) = start1 - taken(m)
    Else
        left1(m) = left1(m) - taken(m)
    End If
```

So on the first run through the value of **left1** is always 0 and it will take it away from the start amount in the batch (**start1**). Then what I want to do, is if it isn't the first run through then the value left should be stored so that the value taken can be subtracted from the last value of **left1**. eg. batch starts at 100 (**start1** = 100), user takes 10 (**taken(m)** = 10) and then **left1** = 90.This works fine as it's the first run through. But then if the user takes another 15 at another time after this, then it should take the 15 from 90 resulting in 75. This is not the case as **left1(m)** is reset after the sub has ended meaning the result shown is 85. Is there anyway to store the values in **left1** to get it do work as described?

Comment: seems like you're storing `left1()` updated values in Sheet5 column E: can't you read its values from there at the beginning of your sub (i.e. `start1 = Sheet3.Range("E" & m)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `Dim left1(5 To 248) As Integer` to `Static left1(5 To 248) As Integer`, left1 will already be instantiated and populated the second time you run the btnEnter_click sub procedure with the values left in the array after the first time the sub procedure was run.

I cannot determine from your code what you plan to do with the repeated values.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a variable as `Static`, as @Jeeped answered, or you could create a public variable outside procedure:

```
Public left1(5 To 248) As Integer

Sub MySub
    'Your code here
End Sub
```